# Extra set of bars on plot in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I want to create a plot using Pandas to show the standard deviations of item prices on specific week days (in my case there are 6 relevant days of the week, each shown as 0-5 on the x axis).

It seems to work however there is another set of smaller bars next to each standard deviation bar that is literally also valued at 0-5.

I think this means that I'm also accidentally also plotting the day of the week.

How can I get rid of these smaller bars and only show the standard deviation bars?

```
sales_std=sales_std[['WeekDay','price']].groupby(['WeekDay']).std()
    .reset_index()
```

Here is where I try to plot the graph:

```
p = sales_std.plot(figsize= 
(15,5),legend=False,kind="bar",rot=45,color="orange",fontsize=16, 
yerr=sales_std);
p.set_title("Standard Deviation", fontsize=18);
p.set_xlabel("WeekDay", fontsize=18);
p.set_ylabel("Price", fontsize=18);
p.set_ylim(0,100);
```

[Resulting Bar Plot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdAAL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are plotting both `WeekDay` and `price` at the same time (i.e. plotting an entire `Dataframe`). In order to show bars for `price` only, you need to plot `Series` given `WeekDay` as an index (so no `reset_index()` is required after `groupby()`).

```
# you don't need `reset_index()` in your code
sales_std=sales_std[['WeekDay','price']].groupby(['WeekDay']).std()
sales_std['price'].plot(kind='bar')
```

Note: I intentionally omitted graph-styling parts of your code to focus on fixing the issue.